# Lock column based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I need to lock columns based on days stated in G8, H8, I8, J8, and K8.

1. I need to lock G9 through G44 if G8 doesn’t have today's day.
2. If today is Sunday and G8 has Sunday then G9 to G44 should be open If not then the data range should be locked.

   This should be done with all the columns from G to K. How can I do that?
   Thanks a million in advance.

   ```
   Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim col As Range
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           .Unprotect "ABCDE"
           For Each col In .UsedRange.Columns
               col.EntireColumn.Locked = col.Range("A1").Value < Date
           Next col
           .Protect "ABCDE"
           .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: What isnt working? Requirement 1 is part of requirement 2, so its just an example? Your code works for me, except for that it only checks for older dates, doesnt lock the date cell itself and once the sheet is locked, its locked and you have to manually unlock it to run this macro. for the last problem, consider running the macro when the workbook is opened/sheet activated as well? `Worksheet_Activate` and `Workbook_Open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your code looks good, all you need to do is to add a few more `If` conditions. Give it a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col                 As Long
    Dim tDate               As Date

    tDate = Date 'today's date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        '.Unprotect "ABCDE"
        For col = 0 To .Range("G9:K44").Columns.Count - 1
            'check if row 8 doesn't have today's date
            If .Range("G8").Offset(0, col).Value <> tDate Then
                'if today is Sunday and row 8 has Sunday
                If Format(tDate, "dddd") = "Sunday" And Format(.Range("G8").Offset(0, col).Value, "dddd") = "Sunday" Then
                    .Range("G8:G44").Offset(0, col).EntireColumn.Locked = False
                Else
                    .Range("G8:G44").Offset(0, col).EntireColumn.Locked = True
                End If
            End If
        Next col
        '.Protect "ABCDE"
        '.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
    End With
End Sub
```

Change `tDate` to some other date to test the code, e.g. `tDate = '2020-02-16'` (Sunday).

Comment: Your code works excellently. I have a question would it change automatically. Like if its monday, will the column will monday unlocked? I need this to lock every column except the one with today's day. And that should change everyday. Thanks a million for your time and support.

Comment: No problem at all. As it is currently set to be a `Worksheet_Change` event, your columns should get locked/unlocked once you make any change to your worksheet (adding/removing/editing/etc). Alternatively, you can add this code to `Workbook_Open` event, in order to make sure that the code triggers automatically when you open an Excel file.

Comment: P.S. Also please remember to upvote/accept the answer if it helped, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: Today is Wednesday. Will this code unlock the Wednesday column? If i use this code it is locking me out. I can't edit Wednesday column. I want the day dynamic. Like on sunday it will open sunday column, on monday it will open monday column and so on. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you requested "if today is Sunday and row 8 has Sunday" (i.e. that you only want this rule to apply to Sundays). In that case use `If Format(tDate, "dddd") = Format(.Range("G8").Offset(0, col).Value, "dddd") Then` instead of `If Format(tDate, "dddd") = "Sunday" And Format(.Range("G8").Offset(0, col).Value, "dddd") = "Sunday" Then`.

Comment: Excellent. Perfectly solved my problem. Thanks a million. Stay Blessed.